# How to return WebBrowser.Element with Selenium and Scala

Tags: scala, selenium, playframework, cucumber

I am writing a helper object in Scala in which I have high level functions to click elements and such, those functions also throw an NoSuchElementException if the required element doesn't exist. I'm doing this mainly to reuse code.
I've got another class (I'm using Cucumber, so this class has the step definitions) wich calls the the other object functions.

The problem is that those functions expect to receive an Option[Element] with the Element coming from org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser.Element, but when I use the finders I get an Element from MyStepClass.this.Element.

Here is a part of my code where I'm getting this problem

```
class CucumberSteps extends ScalaDsl with EN with Matchers with Firefox {
...
When("""^I click the button with id "([^"]*)"$""") { (buttonId: String) =>
  SeleniumUtils.clickOn(find(id(buttonId)))
}
...
}

object SeleniumUtils extends Matchers with Firefox {
...
def clickOn(elem: Option[Element]) {
  applyElement(elem, x => click on (x))
}

def applyElement(elem: Option[Element], f: Element => Unit) {
  elem match {
    case Some(e) => f(e)
    case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException
  }
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced your issue is within `SeleniumUtils`. The class of the wrapped element returned by ScalaTest's `find` method is a subclass of `org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser.Element`, and should be successfully matched in your pattern matching statement.

I would try discarding your `clickOn` utility method and just directly use the ScalaTest Selenium DSL from your test method:

```
...
click on find(buttonId)
...
```

This at the very least will identify one way or the other whether your problem was within `SeleniumUtils`:

- If your test passes or progresses further, then I'm wrong and your problem is indeed within your pattern matching code.
- If your test fails with the same problem (which I assume is a NoSuchElementException), then I'm right and the explanation is a little simpler (you're trying to find a non-existent ID).